# search string inside string

Tags: c#, string, listbox, listboxitem

I'm working on application that's need search method I have listbox full with items every item have singer name and song title , I need be able to search the song title or singer name on same method  that's what's I tried so far :

```
 public void search_song()
    {

        for (int i = listbox_titles.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int char_count = listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().Length;
            if (listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(txt_to_search.Text) || listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().StartsWith(txt_to_search.Text, StringComparison.Ordinal) || listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Substring(0, char_count).Contains(txt_to_search.Text)) ;
            {
                //listbox_titles.SetSelected(i, true);
                MessageBox.Show(listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString());
            }
        }
```

its work but only search from the beginning of items not middle 
any ideas ??

this example of what's I want if item is **avicii waiting for love ** if I search waiting for love is should give me the item .

Comment: Remove everything else except `listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(txt_to_search.Text)` from `if`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya those are `||` operators not `&&` they wont affect the result even if they are unnecessary.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ok man I well try it and come back

Comment: I suggested to remove them coz they are not needed if Contains check is already being done at the first place.

Comment: I try it but didn't work this example of what's I want if item is  **avicii waiting for love ** if I search waiting for love is should give me the item but didn't work @ChetanRanpariya and I remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find the list box item that contains what you search for, so you don't need for `StartsWith` method, but since you're saying that your search method only works on the starting string, I can find that you're not converting the text to lower in `StartsWith` as in `Contains`, and that might what make the issue. So if your check is case insensitive you can just use the following:

```
  public void search_song()
        {

            for (int i = listbox_titles.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int char_count = listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().Length;
                if (listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().IndexOf(txt_to_search.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    //listbox_titles.SetSelected(i, true);
                    MessageBox.Show(listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still give me same problem only detect first words not on middle

Comment: see this link I upload a picture of it [link](https://imgur.com/a/nYGIb)

Comment: Sorry, check now.

Comment: thanks, man that solves my problem I mark your answer as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code isn't like your original when you do get it working because you will always get the message box:

```
        if (listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(txt_to_search.Text) || 
listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().StartsWith(txt_to_search.Text, StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
 listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Substring(0, char_count).Contains(txt_to_search.Text)
) ;

        {
            //listbox_titles.SetSelected(i, true);
            MessageBox.Show(listbox_titles.Items[i].ToString());
        }
```

That green squiggle on the syntax highlighter is pointing you to a warning that it is an empty statement - you have a semi-colon at the end of the if, so your block of code is not conditional at all.

Edit:

```
    public void search_song(string txt_to_search)
    {

        foreach(var t in listbox_titles.Items)
        {
            String s = t.ToString().ToLower();
            if(s.Contains(txt_to_search.ToLower()))
            {
                //listbox_titles.SetSelected(i, true);
                MessageBox.Show(s);
            }
        }

    }
```

This works for me because it keeps the size of the lines down to a manageable level - obviously, you would need to index using a variable rather than foreach.

Edit:

If you need to know where the occurrences are you can always define an extension helper:

```
    public void search_song(string txt_to_search)
    {

        foreach (var t in listbox_titles.Items)
        {

            if(txt_to_search.Occurrences(t.ToString(), false).Count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show(t.ToString());
        }

    }

}
static class StringHelpers
{
    public static List<int> Occurrences(this string pattern, string source, bool caseSensitive = true)
    {
        List<int> occurs = new List<int>();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pattern))
            return occurs;

        int index = 0;
        if (!caseSensitive)
        {
            pattern = pattern.ToLower();
            source = source.ToLower();
        }
        while (index < source.Length) // was (index < source.Length - 1)
        {
            if ((index = source.IndexOf(pattern, index)) < 0)
                break;

            occurs.Add(index);
            ++index;
        }

        return occurs;
    }
}
```

Just capture the list and interrogate it.

Edit: just noticed that I had the scan stop short of the end (no idea why, old age brain fade perhaps). It probably won't make a major difference unless you are searching for single characters (which is what I happened to do!)